# Ошибка компиляции Fortran/Python

Tags: c, ubuntu, компиляция, python-2.7, fortran

В общем я совсем профан в программировании, но мне понадобилось  компилировать программу для математического моделирования. В этих библиотеках задействовано несколько языков (C, C++, Fortran, Lua, Python) Собственно ниже ошибка при компиляции библиотек для нее. Ubuntu запускал на Windows 10. Все предыдущие ошибки были свяавны с отсутствием того или иного ПО, которое я установил, но что делать с этой понятия не имею, других сообщений о таком я не видел, а лезть в такой сложный код своими кривыми руками я не хочу. Буду благодарен любой помощи.

```
make -j 9 Making all in src make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src' Making all in wxml make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/wxml' make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'. make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/wxml' Making all in cml make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/cml' make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'. make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/cml' Making all in sax make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/sax' make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'. make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/sax' Making all in xpath make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/xpath' make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'. make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/xpath' Making all in dom make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/dom' make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'. make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/dom' Making all in . make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src' /bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=FC   --mode=compile gfortran  -g -O2 -c -o xmlf90_info.lo xmlf90_info.f90 libtool: compile:  gfortran -g -O2 -c xmlf90_info.f90  -fPIC -o .libs/xmlf90_info.o libtool: compile:  gfortran -g -O2 -c xmlf90_info.f90 -o xmlf90_info.o >/dev/null 2>&1 /bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=FC   --mode=link gfortran  -g -O2 -version-info 0:0:0 -L/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib -L/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib  -o libxmlf90.la -rpath /mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib xmlf90_info.lo cml/libxmlf90_cml.la dom/libxmlf90_dom.la sax/libxmlf90_sax.la wxml/libxmlf90_wxml.la xpath/libxmlf90_xpath.la libtool: link: rm -fr  .libs/libxmlf90.a .libs/libxmlf90.la .libs/libxmlf90.lai .libs/libxmlf90.so .libs/libxmlf90.so.0 .libs/libxmlf90.so.0.0.0 libtool: link: gfortran -shared  -fPIC  .libs/xmlf90_info.o  -Wl,--whole-archive cml/.libs/libxmlf90_cml.a dom/.libs/libxmlf90_dom.a sax/.libs/libxmlf90_sax.a wxml/.libs/libxmlf90_wxml.a xpath/.libs/libxmlf90_xpath.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -L/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib  -g -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libxmlf90.so.0 -o .libs/libxmlf90.so.0.0.0 libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libxmlf90.so.0" && ln -s "libxmlf90.so.0.0.0" "libxmlf90.so.0") libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libxmlf90.so" && ln -s "libxmlf90.so.0.0.0" "libxmlf90.so") libtool: link: (cd .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_cml.a && ar x "/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/cml/.libs/libxmlf90_cml.a") libtool: link: (cd .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a && ar x "/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/dom/.libs/libxmlf90_dom.a") libtool: link: (cd .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a && ar x "/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/sax/.libs/libxmlf90_sax.a") libtool: link: (cd .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a && ar x "/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/wxml/.libs/libxmlf90_wxml.a") libtool: link: (cd .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_xpath.a && ar x "/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/xpath/.libs/libxmlf90_xpath.a") libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libxmlf90.a  xmlf90_info.o  .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_cml.a/m_wcml.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_cml.a/m_wstml.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_cml.a/xmlf90_cml.o  .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_attribute.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_debug.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_document.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_element.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_error.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_namednodemap.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_node.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_nodelist.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_parse.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_strings.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_types.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_utils.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/xmlf90_dom.o  .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_buffer.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_charset.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_converters.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_debug.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_dictionary.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_elstack.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_entities.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_fsm.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_reader.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_xml_error.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_xml_parser.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/xmlf90_sax.o  .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_array_str.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_buffer.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_core.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_dictionary.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_elstack.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_error.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_escape.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_overloads.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_text.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/xmlf90_wxml.o  .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_xpath.a/m_xpath_api.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_xpath.a/xmlf90_xpath.o ar: u' modifier ignored since D' is the default (see U')
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libxmlf90.a
libtool: link: rm -fr .libs/libxmlf90.lax
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libxmlf90.la" && ln -s "../libxmlf90.la" "libxmlf90.la" )
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src'
Making all in doc
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc'
Making all in Examples
make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc/Examples'
Making all in cml
make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc/Examples/cml'
/bin/bash ../../../libtool  --tag=FC   --mode=link gfortran -I../../../src/cml -I../../../src/wxml -g -O2  -L/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib -L/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib  -o example example.o ../../../src/libxmlf90.la
libtool: link: gfortran -I../../../src/cml -I../../../src/wxml -g -O2 -o .libs/example example.o  -L/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib ../../../src/.libs/libxmlf90.so -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc/Examples/cml'
Making all in dom
make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc/Examples/dom'
gfortran -DPACKAGE_NAME="XMLF90" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="xmlf90" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_STRING="XMLF90\ 1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE_URL="https://launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE="xmlf90" -DVERSION="1.5.4" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=".libs/" -I. -I/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -DDOM_DATA_DIR="/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/"  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -g -O2 -c -o data.o /mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/data.F90
gfortran -DPACKAGE_NAME="XMLF90" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="xmlf90" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_STRING="XMLF90\ 1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE_URL="https://launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE="xmlf90" -DVERSION="1.5.4" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=".libs/" -I. -I/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -DDOM_DATA_DIR="/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/"  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -g -O2 -c -o features.o /mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/features.F90
gfortran -DPACKAGE_NAME="XMLF90" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="xmlf90" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_STRING="XMLF90\ 1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE_URL="https://launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE="xmlf90" -DVERSION="1.5.4" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=".libs/" -I. -I/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -DDOM_DATA_DIR="/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/"  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -g -O2 -c -o pseudo.o /mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/pseudo.F90
gfortran -DPACKAGE_NAME="XMLF90" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="xmlf90" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_STRING="XMLF90\ 1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE_URL="https://launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE="xmlf90" -DVERSION="1.5.4" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=".libs/" -I. -I/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -DDOM_DATA_DIR="/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/"  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -g -O2 -c -o pseudo_dom.o /mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/pseudo_dom.F90
gfortran -DPACKAGE_NAME="XMLF90" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="xmlf90" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_STRING="XMLF90\ 1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE_URL="https://launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE="xmlf90" -DVERSION="1.5.4" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=".libs/" -I. -I/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -DDOM_DATA_DIR="/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/"  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -g -O2 -c -o text.o /mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/text.F90
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/features.F90:9:132:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"test.xml" ) !! , verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/features.F90:9:132:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"test.xml" ) !! , verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
f951: some warnings being treated as errors
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/pseudo.F90:27:132:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"pseudo.xml")  !  ,verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'features.o' failed
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/pseudo.F90:27:123:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"pseudo.xml")  !  ,verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)
make[3]: *** [features.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/data.F90:9:132:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"pseudo.xml",verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/data.F90:9:123:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"pseudo.xml",verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/text.F90:13:132:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"big-file.xml")!! , verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/pseudo_dom.F90:32:132:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"pseudo.xml")  !  ,verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/text.F90:13:123:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"big-file.xml")!! , verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/pseudo_dom.F90:32:123:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"pseudo.xml")  !  ,verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)
f951: some warnings being treated as errors
f951: some warnings being treated as errors
f951: some warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'data.o' failed
make[3]: *** [data.o] Error 1
f951: some warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'pseudo.o' failed
make[3]: *** [pseudo.o] Error 1
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'text.o' failed
make[3]: *** [text.o] Error 1
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'pseudo_dom.o' failed
make[3]: *** [pseudo_dom.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc/Examples/dom'
Makefile:478: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc/Examples'
Makefile:385: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc'
Makefile:528: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
...ending phase build module xmlf90  stderr: ########## Error running make -j 9
*** Error during phase build of xmlf90: ########## Error running make -j 9 *** [8/13]

<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<pseudo version="0.5">

<!-- A full example of Froyen-style pseudopotential file(with reduced data sections) -->


<header core-corrections="nc" polarized="no" relativistic="yes" correlation="ca" flavor="Troullier-Martins" date="no_date" creator="ATM3" zval=" 12.0000000000" symbol="Ti"/>

<grid npts="8" step=" 0.125000000000E-01" scale=" 0.112670553485E-03" units="bohr" type="log"/>


-<semilocal units="rydberg" npots-up="3" npots-down="4" format="r*V">


-<vps spin="-1" occupation=" 2.00000000000" cutoff=" 1.30000000000" l="0" principal-n="3">


-<radfunc>

<grid npts="8" step=" 0.343430000E-01" scale=" 0.235E-03" units="bohr" type="log"/>

<data> -0.331900385172E-04 -0.667975563254E-04 -0.100827804667E-03 -0.135286100838E-03 -0.170177829017E-03 -0.205508441107E-03 -0.241283457588E-03 -0.277508468378E-03 </data>

</radfunc>

</vps>


-<vps spin="-1" occupation=" 6.00000000000" cutoff=" 1.30000000000" l="1" principal-n="3">


-<radfunc>

<data> -0.498621054540E-04 -0.100351398985E-03 -0.151475769648E-03 -0.203243205728E-03 -0.255661795995E-03 -0.308739730957E-03 -0.362485304152E-03 -0.416906913432E-03 </data>

</radfunc>

</vps>


-<vps spin="-1" occupation=" 2.00000000000" cutoff=" 1.30000000000" l="2" principal-n="3">


-<radfunc>

<data> -0.864406179730E-04 -0.173968525070E-03 -0.262597397705E-03 -0.352341084318E-03 -0.443213607544E-03 -0.535229166399E-03 -0.628402138500E-03 -0.722747082314E-03 </data>

</radfunc>

</vps>


-<vps spin="-1" occupation=" 0.00000000000" cutoff=" 1.98000000000" l="3" principal-n="4">


-<radfunc>

<data> -0.469203541965E-04 -0.944308937944E-04 -0.142539042412E-03 -0.191252317045E-03 -0.240578329241E-03 -0.290524786291E-03 -0.341099492429E-03 -0.392310350056E-03 </data>

</radfunc>

</vps>


-<vps spin="+1" occupation=" 6.00000000000" cutoff=" 1.30000000000" l="1" principal-n="3">


-<radfunc>

<grid npts="8" step=" 4545.0000E-01" scale=" 0.888E-03" units="bohr" type="log"/>

<data>0.277250403619E-06 0.557988188005E-06 0.842257219008E-06 0.113010191424E-050.142156725002E-05 0.171669876841E-05 0.201554258430E-05 0.231814539264E-05 </data>

</radfunc>

</vps>


-<vps spin="+1" occupation=" 2.00000000000" cutoff=" 1.30000000000" l="2" principal-n="3">


-<radfunc>

<data>0.369459072892E-07 0.743565368829E-07 0.112237734268E-06 0.150595418459E-060.189435582921E-06 0.228764296510E-06 0.268587704417E-06 0.308912029131E-06 </data>

</radfunc>

</vps>


-<vps spin="+1" occupation=" 0.00000000000" cutoff=" 1.98000000000" l="3" principal-n="4">


-<radfunc>

<data>0.108684130278E-07 0.218735338622E-07 0.330170820757E-07 0.443007988704E-070.557264473500E-07 0.672958127953E-07 0.790107029432E-07 0.908729482692E-07 </data>

</radfunc>

</vps>

</semilocal>


-<valence-charge>


-<radfunc>

<data>0.770415732749E-11 0.312054737246E-10 0.711001067937E-10 0.128001774477E-090.202542230650E-09 0.295371753147E-09 0.407159644529E-09 0.538594745943E-09 </data>

</radfunc>

</valence-charge>


-<pseudocore-charge>


-<radfunc>

<grid npts="8" step=" 4545.0000E-01" scale=" 0.888E-03" units="bohr" type="log"/>

<data>0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.000000000000.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 </data>

</radfunc>

</pseudocore-charge>

</pseudo>

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- SideKick user's guide -->

<!-- (C) 2003 Slava Pestov -->

<!-- jEdit buffer-local properties: -->

<!-- :indentSize=1:noTabs=true:folding=sidekick: -->

<!DOCTYPE book SYSTEM "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.1.2/docbookx.dtd" PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.1.2//EN">

-<book>


-<bookinfo>

<title>SideKick plugin user's guide</title>


-<authorgroup>


-<author>

<firstname>Slava</firstname>

<surname>Pestov</surname>

</author>

</authorgroup>


-<legalnotice>

<title>Legal Notice</title>


-<para>
Permission is granted to copy, distribute and/or modify this documentunder the terms of the GNU Free Documentation License, Version 1.1 orany later version published by the Free Software Foundation; with no 
<quote>Invariant Sections</quote>
, 
<quote>Front-Cover Texts</quote>
or 
<quote>Back-Cover Texts</quote>
, each as defined in the license. A copy ofthe license can be found in the file 
<filename>COPYING.DOC.txt</filename>
included with jEdit. 
</para>

<para>The SideKick plugin itself is released under the GNU General Public License.A copy of the GPL can be found in the jEdit online help. </para>

</legalnotice>

</bookinfo>


-<chapter id="browser">

<title>The structure browser window</title>

<para>The SideKick plugin provides a dockable window in which other plugins candisplay buffer structure. </para>


-<para>

<guimenu>Plugins</guimenu>
>
<guisubmenu>SideKick</guisubmenu>
>
<guimenuitem>StructureBrowser</guimenuitem>
displays the current buffer's structure in adockable window. This window is floating bydefault, but it can be docked into the view in the 
<guibutton>Docking</guibutton>
pane of the 
<guimenuitem>Global Options</guimenuitem>
dialog box. 
</para>

<para>The SideKick plugin automatically parses bufferswhen they are loaded or saved, where possible.Optionally, buffers can also be parsed on the fly, but this uses a fair bit ofmemory and processor power so it is disabled by default. </para>


-<para>

<guimenu>Plugins</guimenu>
>
<guisubmenu>SideKick</guisubmenu>
>
<guimenuitem>Parseon Keystroke</guimenuitem>
is a checkbox menu item that toggles on-the-flyparsing, for the current buffer only. 
</para>


-<para>
The current buffer can be parsed at any other time by clicking the parsebutton in the 
<guimenuitem>Structure Browser</guimenuitem>
window, or byinvoking the 
<guimenu>Plugins</guimenu>
>
<guisubmenu>SideKick</guisubmenu>
>
<guimenuitem>ParseBuffer</guimenuitem>
command. 
</para>


-<para>
Any errors found while parsing the buffer are sent to the 
<application>ErrorList</application>
plugin, which means they are highlightedin the text area, and shown in the 
<guimenu>Plugins</guimenu>
>
<guisubmenu>ErrorList</guisubmenu>
>
<guimenuitem>Error List</guimenuitem>
window. See thedocumentation for the 
<application>ErrorList</application>
plugin for details. 
</para>

<para>Clicking on a node in the tree will move the caret to its location in thebuffer;conversely, moving the caret in the buffer will select the correspondingnode. </para>


-<para>

<keycap>Shift</keycap>
-clicking on a node will select that node in the textarea. 
<keycap>Alt</keycap>
-clicking on a node will narrow the text areadisplay to that node. 
</para>

<para>If the structure browser window is docked into the current view, hovering the mouseover a node will display its attributes in the status bar. </para>

</chapter>


-<chapter id="moving-around">

<title>Moving around</title>


-<para>

<guimenu>Plugins</guimenu>
>
<guisubmenu>SideKick</guisubmenu>
>
<guimenuitem>Goto Previous Asset</guimenuitem>
moves the caret to start of the structureelement (
<quote>asset</quote>
). 
</para>


-<para>

<guimenu>Plugins</guimenu>
>
<guisubmenu>SideKick</guisubmenu>
>
<guimenuitem>Goto Next Asset</guimenuitem>
moves the caret to start of the next asset. 
</para>


-<para>

<guimenu>Plugins</guimenu>
>
<guisubmenu>SideKick</guisubmenu>
>
<guimenuitem>SelectAsset at Caret</guimenuitem>
selects the asset at the caret position. 
</para>

</chapter>


-<chapter id="folding">

<title>Folding</title>


-<para>
The SideKick plugin adds a new 
<quote>sidekick</quote>
fold handler thatfolds the buffer according to the structure tree. See the jEdit user's guidefor general details about folding. 
</para>


-<para>

<guimenu>Plugins</guimenu>
>
<guisubmenu>SideKick</guisubmenu>
>
<guimenuitem>Narrow toAsset at Caret</guimenuitem>
hides all text except that of the asset at thecaret location. This works in any folding mode, not just the 
<quote>sidekick</quote>
mode. 
</para>

</chapter>


-<chapter id="completion">

<title>Completion</title>


-<para>
A completion popup can be shown at any timeby invoking the 
<guimenu>Plugins</guimenu>
>
<guisubmenu>SideKick</guisubmenu>
>
<guimenuitem>ShowCompletion Popup</guimenuitem>
command. Each plugin that uses SideKickimplements its own specific completion behavior; see the plugin documentationfor details. 
</para>

</chapter>


-<chapter id="other-plugins">

<title>Developing SideKick back-ends</title>

<para>By itself the SideKick plugin is not very useful; it relies on other plugins toprovide buffer structure information. This chapter gives a brief overview ofhow it's done. </para>


-<sect1 id="preliminaries">

<title>Preliminaries</title>

<para>First you will also need to add a dependency for the SideKick plugin in your plugin'sproperty file: </para>


-<programlisting>
plugin.MyPlugin.depend.
<replaceable>n</replaceable>
=plugin sidekick.SideKickPlugin 0.1
</programlisting>


-<para>
Note that you must replace 
<replaceable>n</replaceable>
with theappropriate number, as dependency properties must have consecutive numbers. 
</para>


-<para>
All SideKick plugin classes are in the 
<classname>sidekick</classname>
package;you will need to add 
<literal>import</literal>
statements where appropriate. 
</para>


-<para>
Parser instances must be registered in your plugin's 
<function>start()</function>
method using the following method in the 
<classname>SideKickPlugin</classname>
class: 
</para>


-<funcsynopsis>


-<funcprototype>


-<funcdef>
public void 
<function>registerParser</function>

</funcdef>


-<paramdef>
SideKickParser 
<parameter>parser</parameter>

</paramdef>

</funcprototype>

</funcsynopsis>


-<para>
A corresponding method must be called from your plugin's 
<function>stop()</function>
method: 
</para>


-<funcsynopsis>


-<funcprototype>


-<funcdef>
public void 
<function>unregisterParser</function>

</funcdef>


-<paramdef>
SideKickParser 
<parameter>parser</parameter>

</paramdef>

</funcprototype>

</funcsynopsis>

</sect1>


-<sect1 id="class-sidekickparser">

<title>The SideKickParser class</title>


-<para>
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stackoverflow. Можете показать хотябы начало файлов  pseudo.xml и big-file.xml?

Comment: Добавил в тело поста.

Comment: Если что это https://gitlab.com/ElectronicStructureLibrary/esl-bundle, может так будет легче

Comment: Все что я нашел указывает на ограничение количества символов в фортран компиляторе, но вот как его убрать я не понял.

Comment: Я бы ещё перенёс проект с виндового ntfs на родной ext. На всякий случай.

Comment: Если нашли решение, добавьте ответом.

Answer (score 1):

*Перенесено из вопроса*

Разработчик ответил на вопрос, проблема была в длине строк и устранялась с помощью строки `-ffree-line-length-none` в GCC.
В моем конкретном случае мне было достаточно использовать config файл:

```
mkdir build-gcc-ubuntu
cd build-gcc-ubuntu
../jhbuild.py -f ../rcfiles/ubuntu-gcc-serial.rc
```